# Catalog search shows apostrophe a %27, finds nothing

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch, language, character-encoding

When I search for `Cee'd` it converted as `Cee%27d` and shows nothing for search term.

If there is **punctuation** or **diacritic**, it doesn't search anything.

I don't know since when it started do it.

Any idea what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I'd been using 301 redirect in .htaccess for URL trailing slashes removal with directives.

```
RewriteCond %{request_method} ^GET$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ %1 [L,R=301]
```

I added `NE`|`noescape` flag. Such as `&` or `?` or diacritic are no longer converted.

Final RewriteRule:

```
RewriteCond %{request_method} ^GET$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ %1 [L,R=301,NE]
```